# Camel Azure Storage Blob consumer not working as expected (blob consumes continuously)

Tags: apache-camel, azure-blob-storage

I have written a simple route to consume a blob from Azure Blob Storage in camel (version 3.12.0) as given below:

```
 from("azure-storage-blob://{{camelazure}}/{{container1}}?blobName=test.json&serviceClient=#client")
                .to({{filePath}});
```

The blob gets consumed non-stop and the route does not stop. Any inputs on how to implement idempotency while consuming from blob storage ?

Comment: You can either delete the blob from the storage or upload a copy to processed "folder" and delete the original after you've processed the blob. By "folder" I mean adding prefix to the blobName i.e `processed/test.json`.  You can use operations `uploadBlockBlob` and `operation` for this.

Comment: Thanks @PasiÖsterman. This was one option I thought would try if we do not have any other way out. :)

Comment: @PasiÖsterman - I have tried these options to upload to processed, the route runs continuously and also the file does not get uploaded to processed folder, instead the file gets uploaded to the same container:  .to("azure-storage-blob://{{camelazure}}/{{container1}}?blobName=processed/test.json&operation=uploadBlockBlob&serviceClient=#client");. Also tried with  .to("azure-storage-blob://{{camelazure}}/{{container1}}/processed?blobName=test.json&operation=uploadBlockBlob&serviceClient=#client");   Do you have any inputs for this ?

Comment: Yes it gets uploaded to same container but with name `processed/test.json` if you want it to be stored to a different container you'll have to specify different container to the URI with valid credentials for that container. Azure blob storage uses flat file system so there are no real folders, only virtual folders based on the name of the blob.

Comment: Personally I prefer to use quartz consumer endpoint with azure-storage-blob producer endpoint to get the blob from blob storage then process it, copy the blob using name `processed/blobname-datetime` then remove the original blob. Then all processed blobs will be in the same container but in virtual folder named processed with unique blob names.

Comment: Thanks @PasiÖsterman. With the timer component, it worked perfectly :)

Comment: Good to hear. Don't forget to post your solution and accept it as answer so others can benefit from it as well.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Pasi Österman, the below solution worked well when we know the blob name to be downloaded and processed.

```java
from("timer://readBlob?fixedRate=true&period=60000")
    .to("azure-storage-blob://{{camelazure}}/{{container1}}?blobName=test.json&operation=getBlob&serviceClient=#client")
    .process(exchange -> {
        InputStream inputStream = exchange.getMessage().getBody(InputStream.class);
        exchange.getIn().setBody(IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
    })
    .to("file:{{filePath}}")
    .to("azure-storage-blob://{{camelazure}}/{{container1}}?blobName=processed/test.json&operation=uploadBlockBlob&serviceClient=#client")
    .to("azure-storage-blob://{{camelazure}}/{{container1}}?blobName=test.json&operation=deleteBlob&serviceClient=#client");
```